# Trim whitespace from data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I use fread to import very big .CSV-files. Some columns have whitespace after the text that I need to remove. This takes too much time (hours).

The following code works but the command at system.time is very slow (about 12 seconds on my computer, and the real files are much bigger).

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# Create example-data
df.1 <- rbind(c("Text1        ", 1, 2), c("Text2        ", 3, 4), c("Text99       ", 5, 6))

colnames(df.1) <- c("Tx", "Nr1", "Nr2")
dt.1 <- data.table(df.1)
for (i in 1:15) {
  dt.1 <- rbind(dt.1, dt.1)
}

# Trim the "Tx"-column
dt.1[, rowid := 1:nrow(dt.1)]
setkey(dt.1, rowid)
system.time( dt.1[, Tx2 :={ str_trim(Tx) }, by=rowid] )
dt.1[, rowid:=NULL]
dt.1[, Tx:=NULL]
setnames(dt.1, "Tx2", "Tx")
```

Is there a faster way to trim whitespace in data.tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can operate only on unique values of "Tx" (presuming you actually have some repetition, as in your example):

```
dt.1[, Tx2:=str_trim(Tx),     by=1:nrow(dt.1)]
dt.1[, Tx3:=str_trim(Tx),     by=Tx]

dt.1[, all.equal(Tx2,Tx3)]    # TRUE
```

Using `gsub` instead of `str_trim` as in @DWin's answer also speeds things up, whether or not you have duplicated "Tx" values.

**EDIT:** As @DWin pointed out, there's no reason to do it by row to begin with, so `str_trim` doesn't need to be vectorized. So, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Impressive. The change of by-vector is the real improvement. It accelerates the gsub() approach as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
system.time( dt.1[, Tx2 :={ str_trim(Tx) }, by=rowid] )
   user  system elapsed 
 19.026   0.105  19.021 

system.time(  dt.1[,  Tx2 := gsub("\\s+$", "", as.character(Tx)), by=rowid]) 
   user  system elapsed 
  4.789   0.053   4.773
```

Comment: I wonder why hadley's function is so slow. Anyway, no need for a `by` with gsub, right?

Comment: I think it's a misspecification of the 'by' vector. Omitting it saves substantial time and I see no particular reason it should be there. Your `by=Tx` version was even faster, though.

Comment: Oh, I see, str_trim is already vectorized. I just assumed that that was why the OP was doing the nrow stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_trim` from the stringr package and `mutate` from dplyr

```
df %>%
mutate(column1 = str_trim(column1))
```